# How to bind a specific declaration file to a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an old project written in JS and Vue2, the build tool is Webpack. I want to add TypeScript support for this old project, but there is something confusing me.

Suppose I have below code structure:

```
|--infrastructure
| |--common
| | |--utils
| | | |--browsers.js
```

Then I will add an alias config in Webpack to point to the infrastructure folder:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@infra': path.join('...', 'infrastructure')
  }
}
```

In my `tsconfig.json`, I add the path config:

```
"paths": {
  "@infra/*": [
    "infrastructure/*"
  ]
}
```

Then I run below command in the project root folder:

```
npx -p typescript tsc infrastructure/**/*.js --declaration --declarationMap --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir types
```

After above command, it will generate a types folder with below code structure:

```
|--types
| |--infrastructure
| | |--common
| | | |--utils
| | | | |--browsers.d.ts
| | | | |--browsers.d.ts.map
```

Then add typeRoots config to include the new generated `types` folder in tsconfig.json:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
```

How do I bind the new generated declaration file with the existing JavaScript file? Like when I write below codes in a Vue component:

```
import browserUtils from '@infra/common/utils/browsers'
```

How does the compiler get the declaration of `@infra/common/utils/browsers`? Now it always gets the error "**Cannot find module '@views/common/utils/browsers' or its corresponding type declarations**"

Comment: the compiler does not need the declaration files anyway, usually you have tslint installed that will look for the declaration and report any issue, and it does that using the tsconfig.json file, it looks for the typeRoots, and find the declarations this way, it will also search for .d.ts files in your src automatically

Comment: usually we just put a '.d.ts' file in the same place with '.js' file and with same name.

Comment: Is there any other method ? Since this will inject many '.d.ts' in original source files.